# Retain formatting when pasting into Gmail & Yahoo Mail on Firefox

Tags: gmail, yahoo-mail, text-formatting

I tend to write somewhat complex responses to friends that include **bold** and *italics* as well as font size and color changes (not available here?).

I take my time and do it offline using Word or somesuch, but then copying my formatted text and pasting it into Gmail and Yahoo Mail removes all my lovely taradiddles, y'know?

What to do?

Comment: does Ctrl+Shift+C and Ctrl+Shift+V work with special copy and paste?